# How to delete element from array in N1QL

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

I am new to N1QL, I want to delete matching string from array.

Here is my required array called inspection:

```
 "job_1": {
    "inspection": ['11','22','33','44'] //This is Array
  },
  "job_2": {
    "inspection": ['22','33','44'] //This is Array
  },
  "job_3": {
    "inspection": ['11','22'] //This is Array
  }
```

i want to delete '22' from all 3 array located inside each job (it may be possible that value which i wants to delete is not present in inspection array):

How do i delete that using delete query, Can any one help me to get query ?

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 3):

Use WHERE clause to update the document that has required value. After that use ARRAY construct to form new ARRAY and assign it. You can also use ARRAY functions.

```
UPDATE default AS d
SET d.inspection = ARRAY v FOR v IN d.inspection WHEN v != "22" END
WHERE "22" IN d.inspection;
```

OR

```
UPDATE default AS d
SET d.inspection = ARRAY v FOR v IN d.inspection WHEN v != "22" END
WHERE ANY v IN d.inspection SATISFIES v = "22" END;
```

Reference

https://blog.couchbase.com/working-json-arrays-n1ql/
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html